# Can we use a different subdomain than 'stun'/'turn' for a STUN / TURN Server?

Tags: webrtc, nat, stun, turn

All the documentation / tutorials for setting up a STUN / TURN server suggest that we need to create two subdomains namely:

- `stun.yourdomain.com`
- `turn.yourdomain.com`

And then these can be accessed as:

- `stun:stun.yourdomain.com:5349`
- `turn:turn.yourdomain.com:3478`

Is it possible to register subdomains with different names than "stun" and "turn" ?
Has anyone tried / created subdomains as:

- `stun:somothername.yourdomain.com:5349` ?

Is there any official documentation / reference that can be used to understand this in more detail?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand [RFC 5389](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5389) correctly, there is no requirement to use specific domain names, on the contrary:

> Hard-coding the domain name of the server into software is
> NOT RECOMMENDED in case the domain name is lost or needs to change
> for legal or other reasons.

(from section 9)

As long as you follow the advice in that section for DNS Discovery, you should be able to use any domain/host name you like.